# useSession() hook returning undefined in NextJS v13.4.3

Tags: authentication, session, authorization, next-auth, next.js13

I am new to NextJS and I am using v13.4.3. My backend is performing auth and upon login, it is returning a JWT as `HTTPONLY` cookie which is attached to the browser. My requirement is to build components on the frontend that have conditional buttons/text based on whether the user is logged in or not.

My understanding is that I can use the `useSession` hook in my components to grab the session from the cookie when the page is rendering and this should tell me whether the user is logged in or not. The problem is that the `useSession` hook is always returning undefined.

Here is my code and structure. I am using the app structure since I am on the newer version of Next as June 2023.

In my app folder, I have created a folder called auth which has a file called auth-context.tsx -
**src/app/auth/auth-context.tsx**

```
'use client';

import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

export interface AuthContextProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function AuthContext({ children }: AuthContextProps) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}
```

In my app folder in the main layout file -
**src/app/layout.tsx**

```
import '@styles/global.css';
import AuthContext from './auth/auth-context';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'myTitle',
  description:
    'myDescription',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <AuthContext>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </body>
      </html>
    </AuthContext>
  );
}
```

I have done the above in order to wrap the useSession in a sessionProvider by creating a separate client as mentioned by NextJS documentation. I followed this thread to learn about this - https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/5647

Now the component that needs access to the session is sitting in the (dashboard) folder in app folder -
**src/app/(dashboard)/home/page.tsx**

```
'use client';

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function Home() {
  const { data } = useSession();
  console.log('LINE7', data);

  return (
    <div>
      HOME
      <p>{data?.user?.name}</p>
      <p>{data?.user?.email}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the object data always comes back as undefined when I navigate to the home page. When I check the browser, I am seeing the cookie being passed correctly. I decoded the cookie on jwt.io and it is the right cookie that my backend is passing. So it seems like my login functionality is working fine but I am unable to grab the session.

The console in the browser logs this - **LINE7 null**
The console in vs code logs this - **LINE7 undefined**

Has anyone faced this problem before? If so, could you please guide me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for people with similar issues, here is an update - I think my issue was that I wasn't using `next-auth` on the server side. What I mean is that my "*server*" in this case is a proper back repository in NestJS. I believe for the `useSession()` hook to work properly and grab data from the browser, your server has to also be in NextJS using `next-auth`.

I did not want to rewrite my entire server side auth so I moved away from this strategy to grab the session on the client using `useSession()`. I devised another strategy instead where my backend (NestJS) is passing two cookies, one that is `HttpOnly` and one that is **not** `HttpOnly`. These two cookies together do the trick for me and allow to recognize if a user is logged in on the frontend. They also allow me to validate the user when accessing any backend resources.

Do let me know if you want more context on that and I can share more details.

Good luck!